# Where did my custom attribute assembly reference go?

Tags: .net, custom-attributes

I've got the following code in `AssemblyA`:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(AssemblyB.TestTypeConverter))]
public class TestClass
{

}
```

`TestTypeConverter` is defined in a different assembly (`AssemblyB`). This is the only reference to `AssemblyB` from `AssemblyA`. When I compile this & have a look in reflector, the TypeConverterAttribute is there, but `AssemblyA` doesn't have any assembly references to AssemblyB.dll; it's only got mscorlib and System.dll. Where did it go, and how does .NET know to look in `AssemblyB` for `TestTypeConverter`?

Comment: Run your assembly through `ildasm /all` and look at metadata tables.

Comment: I've had a look at it in CFF Explorer, and the only two AssemblyRef entries are System.dll and mscorlib

Comment: The "assembly" tag is for assembly language programming. I have deleted it, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate this on my box and cannot see it. When I reference AssemblyB.TestTypeConverter in AssemblyA,  Reflector correctly says that AssemblyA references AssemblyB.

Is TestClass marked up wihth the attribute in Reflector? If so, what happens when you click on the attribute in Reflector?

Comment: The attribute displays ok in reflector, and clicking on the typeof() opens AssemblyB & navigates to the type, but in the 'References' list there is only System and mscorlib. Are you sure nothing else is referencing AssemblyB from AssemblyA?